# Keep reference to new operator

Tags: javascript

I have multiple video's on a page. When I click the play button on one of the video's (app.js) the data is retrieved and myVideo.init is called (video.js). This works but the problem is that the data of the previous video instance is always overwritten, I would somehow like to keep this intact because it contains information on when the player was started/paused etc. In theory it would need to be possible to:

1. Start video A
2. Pause video A
3. Start video B
4. Start video A again from the same coordinates it was paused, but this data was lost when I started video B.

I hope my question is clear enough. Help would be much appreciated.

```js
// video.js
export default new (Base.extend({
    myVideo: null,
    
    init(clip) {
        this.myVideo = new videoObject({}, 'https://localhost.nl?video123');
        this.myVideo.setProperties()
    }
}))();

// app.js
export default Base.extend({

  state: {
    isFirstTimePlaying: []
  },

  util.getJson({url: 'test.json'}).done((data) => {
      let id = this.getPlayerId();

      if (!this.state.isFirstTimePlaying.includes(id)) {
          myVideo.init(data, id);
          this.state.isFirstTimePlaying.push(id);
      }
  });
}))();
```

Comment: You can just push the information off to the side in a service of some kind. A JS singleton, something like that. I used to use video.js pretty extensively at Bloomberg, that's how we did it. Even a plain ol' static global script that just holds the bits of video information works perfectly.

Comment: thanks for your reply, note that this is not actually video.js (as in the library you probably mean) this is something I created by myself. I guess a JS singleton could work but all my events inside app.js would have to know when to reference which instance.